# Windows Batch Scripting Issue - Quoting Variables containing spaces

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd, spaces

So here's my issue:
I want to use %cd% so a user can execute a script anywhere they want to place it, but if %cd% contains spaces, then it will fail (regardless of quotes).  If I hardcode the path, it will function with quotes, but if it is a variable, it will fail.

Fails: (if %cd% contains spaces)
"%cd%\Testing.bat"

Works:
"C:\Program Files\Testing.bat"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`%CD%` is not the right way to do it, as it indicates the directory where *the user* was located when invoking the script, not the directory where the script resides.

Use `%~dp0` instead to extract the drive and path information from `%0`:

```
REM C:\Program Files\test_caller.bat
@echo I am the caller and I reside in: "%~dp0"
@"%~dp0\test.bat"
```

...

```
REM C:\Program Files\test.bat
@echo Yippeee!
```

...

```
C:\>"\Program Files\test_caller.bat"
I am the caller and I reside in: "C:\Program Files\"
Yippeee!

C:\>e:

E:\>"C:\Program Files\test_caller.bat"
I am the caller and I reside in: "C:\Program Files\"
Yippeee!
```